# How to build a layout like this?

Tags: android, layout

I want to build an activity with the following design. Up until now I just used relative and linear layouts.
Is it possible to make the following design with this group views or should I be useing something else?

[image: my desired layout]

I want to put some animations on the shapes no.2 and no.3 but not the "text1" and "text2".
What should I do? Is it possible to design this only in my xml file or should I be doing some work in my java code?
* just the colored part is the layout , the numbers and the arrows are not part of it.

Comment: i suggest you posting what you have done so far, and what's in it you want to change to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did, I used 3 invisible views to help me put my imageviews where I want them.
As for the sizes, I will use "dimens.xml" and different values for different screen sizes.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background" >

<View
    android:id="@+id/center"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<view
    android:id="@+id/up"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/center"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/center"/>

 <view
    android:id="@+id/down"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/center"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/center"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/p_button"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/down"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/up"
    android:src="@drawable/p"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/s_button"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/up"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/down"
    android:src="@drawable/s"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```